# Passing value from view in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am passing a value from view(entered by user) to controller method which in turn fetches data from DB. Below is the code in my view

```
<%= form_tag({:controller=>"billings", :action=>"tablebill"}, method: :get) do %>
  <div class="center-data">Table Number:
    <div class="tinput"> <%= text_field_tag(:tableno) %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ebutton">
    <%= submit_tag "Enter" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Value tableno is what I need in my controller method and is coded as below

```
def tablebill
  @orders = List
   .select("itemname,tableno,quantity,amount")
   .where(:tableno => params[:tableno]).to_a

  @orders.each do |order|
    @totamount = @totamount + order.amount
  end

  @tax = @totamount/5
  @finalamount = @totamount + @tax

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # tablebill.html.erb
  end  
end
```

The value is being passed successfully in the query but its returning nil. Below is the snippet from my server

```
Started GET "/billings/tablebill?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tableno=08&commit=Enter" for 127
.0.0.1 at 2013-09-05 15:50:01 +0530
  Processing by BillingsController#tablebill as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "tableno"=>"08", "commit"=>"Enter"}
  List Load (1.0ms)  SELECT itemname,tableno,quantity,amount FROM `lists` WHERE
`lists`.`tableno` = '08'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 230ms

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+):
  app/controllers/billings_controller.rb:8:in `block in tablebill'
  app/controllers/billings_controller.rb:7:in `each'
  app/controllers/billings_controller.rb:7:in `tablebill'
```

Problem is when I execute same query on rails console, its giving results. Below is snippet from rails console

```
irb(main):073:0> @orders = List.select("itemname,tableno,quantity,amount").where(:tableno => '08')
=> [#<List tableno: "08", itemname: "test81 ", quantity: "1", amount: "
3.25">, #<List tableno: "08", itemname: "Test82", quantity: "1", amou
nt: "3.75">, #<List tableno: "08", itemname: "Test83", quantity: "1
", amount: "3.75">]
```

I have tried a lot with almost all values present in DB but every time its same when done through view and I get results when executing query through rails console. I have tried a lot before posting here as i don't think any issue in passing the value. Its just that the select query isn't working. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: did you checked what value is coming in `params[:tableno]` in controller?????

Comment: yes..its 08. thats what is passed from view.

Comment: What's the field type of `:tableno`?

Comment: its jst a simple mistake i think try this `params[:tableno].to_i`

Comment: @depa : its text value

Comment: @Sagar.Patil tried as suggested but got other error.

Comment: check if the datatype of `tableno` in table and in `params` are same

Comment: yes both are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's because `params[:tableno]` is nil I think it is because you haven't initialized `@totamount`. Then when you try to add the first `order.amount` to it you are getting an error because you can't add to `nil`.

Try either setting `@totamount = 0` before your loop or doing:

```
@totamount = order.map(&:amount).inject(&:+)
```

To add all the amounts together.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell. I tried as suggested but now its not giving any error but not fetching the values either. Its going to next page as mentioned in my method "format.html # tablebill.html.erb". Its displaying page but no vlaues are populated. Instead its displaying '@totamount', '@tax' but not the values. So I assume the values were not calculated.

Comment: That sounds like you are putting `@totamount` and `@tax` in your view without doing, for example, `<%= @totamount %>`

Comment: oops..thanks for pointing this mistake. Just checked after correcting this but again hard luck. No values this time. Everything blank. Checked again on console. All values are getting calculated as expected.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell. I figured out the problem. All set now. Thanks again for everything.